# Noetherian and Artinian quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian, artinian

Let $I$ be a left ideal of ring $R$. My question is can we lift both Noetherian and Artinian property of $R/I$ as an $R$-module to $R$ as an $R$-module?

Precisely, can we say that $R$ is a left Noetherian (Artinian) $R$-module if and only if  $R/I$ is left Noetherian (Artinian) $R$-module?

Comment: No, consider the case $I=R$. However if we furthermore know that $I$ is noetherian/artinian then it is true (at least in the commutative case)

Comment: Before asking a general question, why not try a few examples yourself? Start with $R=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: One has to be careful here. Only rings have separately left and right version of Artin (Noether) property. Modules are by their nature either left or right and the properties int hem do not have *sides*. We can say ring $R$ is right Artininan, or right $R$-module $R$ is Artinian. When we have right ideal $I$ then (cyclic) right $R-$module $R/I$ is not *right Artinian* it is just *Artinian*. Here also I want to stress that unless $I$ is two-sided, factor $R/I$ isn't a ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One implication**
If $R$ as left $R-$module is (Noetherian) Artinian then $R/I$ is too. Suppose it is not, suppose we have infinite (ascending) descending chain of modules in $R/I$ then we have *the same* (ascending) descending chain of submodules in $R$.

(Recall that lattice (poset) of left ideals containing $I$ is the same as a lattice of submodules in cyclic $R-$module $R/I$ by correspondence theorem.)

This is true even more generally for any lattice. If there are no infinite (ascending) descending chains in lattice $\mathcal{L}$ then there can't be such chains in the sublattices defined as all elements that are above some element $I$.

**Second implication** As noted in comments there are some trivial cases when it fails, like $R/R$ is always Artinian for any ring $R$.

**However**, (and this is special for modules, i.e. for Artinian/Noetherian property not true in general lattices), if $M$ is $R-$module such that $N$ and $M/N$ are (Noetherian) Artinian submodules,  for some $R-$submodule $N$ then $M$ itself is (Noetherian) Artinian. (and as a consequence for any submodules $K$ it holds that $K$, $M/K$ are Artin.)